# ODE for the inverse of fundamental solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus, fundamental-solution

Let $A:[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a continuous function, and let $\Phi$ satisfy $\frac{d}{d t} \Phi_t=A_t \Phi_t$ for all $t\in [0,T]$, and $\Phi_0=I_n$. I hope to prove
that the solution to the linear equation
$$
\frac{d}{d t} \Psi_t=- \Psi_tA_t, \quad t\in [0,T]; \quad \Psi_0=I_n,
\tag1
$$
is the matrix inverse of $\Phi$, i.e. ,$\Psi_t:=\Phi_t^{-1}$ for all $t\in [0,T]$.
By definition, $\Psi_0\Phi_0=\Phi_0\Psi_0=I$. Hence
it suffices to verify $\frac{d}{dt}(\Psi\Phi)_t=\frac{d}{dt}(\Phi\Psi)_t=0$ for all $t\in [0,T]$. The identity $\frac{d}{dt}(\Psi\Phi)_t=0$ is easy, but I met some difficulty in proving $\frac{d}{dt}(\Phi\Psi)_t=0$. Below please find my calculation:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}(\Phi_t\Psi_t)^i_j=\sum_{k}\frac{d}{dt}\left((\Phi_t)^i_k(\Psi_t)^k_j\right)
=\sum_{k,l}\left((A_t)^i_l(\Phi_t)^l_k(\Psi_t)^k_j+(\Phi_t)^i_k\left(-(\Psi_t)^k_l(A_t)^l_j\right)\right),
\end{align*}
which does not seem to be zero. Have I overlooked anything?

---

Note that $\Phi_t$ is invertible and $\Psi_t$ is a left-inverse of $\Phi_t$. Hence by the [invertible matrix theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix),  $\Psi_t$ should be the unique right-inverse of $\Phi_t$.

Comment: $\Psi$ is the matrix inverse of $\Phi$? If so, $\Phi\Psi = \Psi\Phi = I_n$, which is constant. Although that would run into the question of what to do if $\Phi$ becomes singular at some point.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes. $\Psi$ is the matrix inverse of $\Phi$. It is well-known that $\Psi$ exists for all $t\in [0,T]$. Here I try to prove that $\Psi$ satisfies a given ODE. As $\Psi_0\Phi_0=\Phi_0\Psi_0=I_n$, it suffices to prove that $\Psi\Phi$ and $\Phi\Psi$ have zero gradients.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Several books claim that the solution of (1) is the inverse of $\Phi$. But they only verify $\frac{d}{d t}(\Psi\Phi)_t=0$ and comment that $\frac{d}{d t}(\Phi\Psi)_t=0$ follows from similar arguments.

Comment: Ah, I see. The goal is to prove the solution to that differential equation is the matrix inverse of $\Phi$, not that the matrix inverse of $\Phi$ satisfies that differential equation, yes?

Comment: @eyeballfrog You are right. The goal is to prove the solution to (1) is the matrix inverse of $\Phi$. But I feel it is equivalent to the matrix inverse of $\Phi$ satisfies (1), due to the uniqueness of matrix inverse of $\Phi$ and solutions to (1).

Comment: Your formula is correct. Just sum over index $k$ so that matrices $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ will together turn to identity matrix. Then, summation over $l$ will do nothing and you will end up subtracting $A^i_j$ from $A^i_j$.

Comment: @Tomek Do you mind elaborating more and turning the comment into an answer?

Comment: @John see my answear.

Comment: @John you are right, I made a mistake in my reasoning.

Comment: The adjoint system of the ODE $x'(t) = A(t) x(t)$ is usually defined as $p'(t) = - A'(t) p(t)$. It is easy to show that ${d \over dt} < p(t), x(t) > = 0$. The state transition matrices between the two systems satify a relation as stated in the problem (in a different way) which can be easily proved. I can give a proof but definition of adjoint system is different, which will take me more time to type..